# Equivalence of two ways of reversing a list

Tags: proof, idris

Let's say I have two different functions that reverse a list:

```
revDumb : List a -> List a
revDumb [] = []
revDumb (x :: xs) = revDumb xs ++ [x]

revOnto : List a -> List a -> List a
revOnto acc [] = acc
revOnto acc (x :: xs) = revOnto (x :: acc) xs

revAcc : List a -> List a
revAcc = revOnto []
```

and now I want to prove that these functions indeed do the same thing. This is the proof that I came up with:

```
mutual
  lemma1 : (acc, lst : List a) -> revOnto acc lst = revOnto [] lst ++ acc
  lemma1 acc [] = Refl
  lemma1 lst (y :: ys) = let rec1 = lemma1 (y :: lst) ys
                             rec2 = lemma2 y ys in
                         rewrite rec1 in
                         rewrite rec2 in
                         rewrite appendAssociative (revOnto [] ys) [y] lst in Refl

  lemma2 : (x0 : a) -> (xs : List a) -> revOnto [x0] xs = revOnto [] xs ++ [x0]
  lemma2 x0 [] = Refl
  lemma2 x0 (x :: xs) = let rec1 = lemma2 x xs
                            rec2 = lemma1 [x, x0] xs in
                        rewrite rec1 in
                        rewrite sym $ appendAssociative (revOnto [] xs) [x] [x0] in rec2

revsEq : (xs : List a) -> revAcc xs = revDumb xs
revsEq [] = Refl
revsEq (x :: xs) = let rec = revsEq xs in
                   rewrite sym rec in lemma2 x xs
```

This even type checks and is total (despite the mutual recursion):

```
*Reverse> :total revsEq
Reverse.revsEq is Total
```

Note that `lemma1` is effectively a stronger version of the `lemma2`, yet I seemingly need `lemma2` since it simplifies the recursive case in `lemma1`.

The question is: can I do any better? Mutually recursive lemmas with lots of rewrites seem to be overly opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the recursion on a function that keeps `revOnto`'s accumulator explicit, the proof can be quite short:

```
lemma1 : (acc, xs : List a) -> revOnto acc xs = revDumb xs ++ acc
lemma1 acc [] = Refl
lemma1 acc (y :: xs) =
    rewrite lemma1 (y :: acc) xs in
    appendAssociative (revDumb xs) [y] acc

revsEq : (xs : List a) -> revAcc xs = revDumb xs
revsEq [] = Refl
revsEq (x :: xs) = lemma1 [x] xs
```